# StandardContextMenu internationalization in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

What is the best way to translate (localize) context menu in QPlaintTextEdit in PyQt ?

For example :

`popup_menu = self.createStandardContextMenu()
popup_menu.insertMenu(popup_menu.actions()[0], QMenu(self.tr("My menu")))`

Here, i can translate "My menu" (pylupdate4, then lrelease) but not all others standards items like "cut", "past", ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context menu for `QPlaintTextEdit` is provided by an internal `QTextControl` class (which is also used by other widgets like `QTextEdit`), and the text of each menu item is already wrapped in a `tr` call. So any applications that want these strings translated just needs to ensure that they load the appropriate translation file for the Qt library itself.

Qt provides translation files for twenty or so languages, which should normally be installed along with the Qt library. The location of these files can be determined programmatically like this:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> print QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath)
/usr/share/qt/translations
```

If there is no translation file for a language, it will be necessary to create one from a template. A template can be obtained by stripping an existing translation file using Qt's `lconvert` tool:

```
lconvert --drop-translations -o qt_xx.ts qt_fr.qm
```

For further details on producing and using translations, see [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/internationalization.html#produce-translations).